# Phonegap + Jquery mobile app not working on android device

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, cordova

I developed a simple JQM app and I'm using Phonegap to compile it for Android and iOS. The app works perfectly on chrome, but it doesn't work on my android device (Nexus s). The app makes a few calls to a REST API i deplyed on a cloud service. Does anyone have this same issue? I'm using the cloud service by phonegap to compile the app. Thanks.

```
$.getJSON( serverURL + "elementi/categoria/0", function( data ){
    $.each( data, function(key, value) {
        vetrina.push(value);
        vetrinaImg.push('<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="' + serverURL + 'items/' + value._id['$id'] +'/1.jpg" /></div>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Need more details. What exactly isnt working? Nothing at all renders? Just the services arent working? Post some code. Help us help you.

Comment: I'm sorry. The rendering is ok. It's the communication with the REST API not working. I don't really know what to post... you know it's a quit big project, but I'm talking about simple ajax calls with jquery and Backbone.js.

Comment: Post the code relevant to the ajax calls.

Comment: $.getJSON( serverURL + "elementi/categoria/0", function( data ) {

    $.each( data, function(key, value) {

     vetrina.push(value);
      vetrinaImg.push('<div class="swiper-slide"><img src="' + serverURL + 'items/' + value._id['$id'] +'/1.jpg" /></div>');

    });
});

But everything works ok on the browser, but not on the android device.

Comment: I am not too familiar with backbone.js but from what you posted everything looks fine. Try some brute force testing. Add alert(value); at the top of your $.each loop, recompile, install app, and see if it is getting any data back or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may forgot to allow access to your server,
you may use  `<access origin="*" />` to your config.xml file to allow access to all urls just for testing.